# For S3 site, how to configure S3, Route53, and Cloudfront to always use the root domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

Using Route53, how can I configure a Cloudfront enabled S3 site to always use a root/naked domain?

Take for example, well, a domain called example.com. First, I know one needs to create two buckets, www.example.com and example.com. Beyond this, it gets tricky when using Cloudfront and Route53.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out:

**S3**

- Put the contents of your site in bucket example.com. Note the Endpoint URL. In my case, it's something like **example.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com**.
- In Properties for example.com bucket, set '**Enable web hosting**'
- In properties for www.example.com bucket, set '**Redirect all requests to another host name**' and **Redirect all requests to** set to example.com

**CloudFront**

Create a CloudFront distribution with origin: example.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com (note, when using CloudFront, the default origin options in the picklist appeared as example.com.s3.amazonaws.com, but it should be example.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com. The former is US Standard which is US east and should work, but I ran into issues).

**Route53**

For example.com hosted zone, create two DNS records (should already have an NS and SOA record if zone for example is on Route53):

## 1

- Type: A
- Name: (blank) - (therefore root/naked domain, example.com)
- Alias: Yes
- Alias Target: 'some cloudfront id'.cloudfront.net.

## 2

- Type: CNAME
- Name: www (therefore www.example.com)
- Alias: No
- Value: example.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com